# React+Redux: Not able to pass in even.target.id to event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that is a context menu and another component that is a table.

I am trying to pass in the `event.target.id` to my event handler but I noticed that it is passing in the previous `event.target.id` and not the current one.

I first put `cellId` in `this.state` and tried to update it in `handleContextMenu`, then tried to pass it into `onDeleteColumn` and `onDeleteRow`. But the value for `event.target.id` did not get saved. So now I tried to pass it straight into `onDeleteRow` and `onDeleteColumn` but it is saying that it cannot read property of undefined.

`EditableTable.js`

```
class EditableTable extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        open: false,
        isOpenContext: false,
        isOpenHeader: false,
    }

    this.handleContextMenu = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.id);

        this.setState({
            isOpenHeader: true,
            anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
        });
    }

 ........
 (within render)

    timelineRows.map((row, rowIndex) => {        ////index is number of rows
                    return <tr id={"row"+" "+rowIndex} key={rowIndex}><td style={tableStyles.numbers}>{rowIndex+1}</td>{
                        headers.map((title, titleIndex) => {
                            return <input name={"cells"} data-row={rowIndex+1} data-column={titleIndex} id={[rowIndex+1] +" "+ titleIndex} style={tableStyles.header} 
                            key={[rowIndex+1] +" "+ titleIndex} 
                            defaultValue={row[headers[titleIndex]]} 
                            onChange={(event) => this.props.handleTableChange(event.target.id, event.target.value)} 
                            onKeyDown={(event) => this.bindKeyboard(event)}

                            *****************************************
                            onContextMenu={(event) =>this.handleContextMenu(event)} /> 
                            *****************************************
                        })
                    }
                    </tr>
                })

............
(Within return)
(Here is my context component)
        <TableContextMenu
            openContext={this.state.isOpenContext}
            anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
            anchorOrigin= {{horizontal:"left",vertical:"top"}}
            targetOrigin= {{horizontal:"right",vertical:"top"}}

            *****************************************
            onDeleteColumn={(event)  => this.props.onColumnDelete(event.target.id)}
            onDeleteRow={(event) => this.props.onRowDelete(event.target.id)}
            ******************************************

            handleCloseContext={this.closeContext} />
```

`EditableTable Container`

```
const deleteRow = (dispatch, cellId) => {
console.log("deleteRow " + cellId);
dispatch(tableActions.rowDelete(cellId));
}

const deleteColumnByHeader = (dispatch, cellId) => {
// console.log(" fsdf");
console.log("header delete " + cellId);
dispatch(tableActions.columnHeaderDelete(cellId));
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
let experimentState = state.experimentState;
let timeline = experimentState[experimentState.previewId];
return{
    timeline_variables: timeline.parameters.timeline_variables,
    randomize_order: timeline.parameters.randomize_order,
    sampling: timeline.parameters.sampling,
}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
onColumnDelete: (cellId) => { deleteColumn(dispatch, ownProps, cellId) },
onRowDelete: (cellId) => { deleteRow(dispatch, ownProps, cellId) },
onColumnDeleteByHeader: (cellId) => { deleteColumnByHeader(dispatch, ownProps, cellId) }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditableTable);
```

Comment: Change the `id` to `id={(rowIndex+1) + " " + (titleIndex+1)}`? What is your overall goal because this approach doesn't look very "react-like"? It's rare to need to bother with `id`s in react outside of styling.

Comment: So basically, when the user right clicks on a table cell, if it's not the header then I want it to display 2 menu items('delete row' and 'delete column'). In my store I have `timeline_variables` that is an array of objects, which I turn into an array of arrays(to make it easier to change values and headers), delete the row/column specified, and then turn back into an array of objects. I need the id's because that is also how I can access that row/column in timeline_variables.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It looks like you could simply do `onContextMenu={(event) => this.handleContextMenu(event,  rowIndex, titleIndex)` instead of dealing with the elements' `id`s. This way you would still have the row and column (if I understand it correctly) but it would be a little cleaner and easier to use.

Comment: You're right that it makes it easier and cleaner, but how can I pass it into onDeleteColumn and onDeleteRow? I created rowIndex and set it to rowIndex in the setState in handleContextMenu. Then I tried to pass `this.state.rowIndex` to onDeleteColumn (`onDeleteColumn={(event)  => this.props.onColumnDelete(event, this.state.rowIndex)}`) but in my container it prints out [object Object].

Comment: It's hard to tell since I don't know how these components come together. I'd probably have something like `selectedRow` and `selectedColumn` in the state of the parent component. The `onColumnDelete` and `onRowDelete` in the parent container wouldn't need anything passed to them from `TableContextMenu` as they would already have the row and column in `this.state`. Sorry, it's kind of hard to explain without knowing how your component structure looks.

Comment: I just realized your question has a redux tag. Are you currently using redux? If so, that makes things potentially much easier.

Comment: Yes I am using redux. I have a container where the rowIndex and titleIndex should be passed to.

Comment: In `handleContextMenu` you can dispatch an action to put the selected row and column in your redux store. In your container around `TableContextMenu` you can use `connect` and retrieve the row and column.

Comment: Awesome. It works now. Thank you so much! I'm still getting used to StackOverflow so is there a way I can give you that 'green check'?

Comment: I would have to create an answer for you to mark as correct. I only posted comments here (they don't really count). I guess I could go ahead and create one.

Comment: I added an answer. Glad you got it working, by the way! I was starting to think I wasn't giving the clearest explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `id` to determine the row and column of the item, you can simply pass the row and column themselves in the event handler.

This can be done by changing your line with `onContextMenu=...` to

```
onContextMenu={(event) => this.handleContextMenu(event, rowIndex, titleIndex)
```

Inside `handleContextMenu` you can dispatch an action with the row and column and keep it in your redux store. From there you can use redux's `connect` on any component to get access to the row and column.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using an arrow function to bind the context of this to the handleContextMenu function you can rewrite that portion to:

```
    handleContextMenu = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      //more code...
  }
```

also, an arrow function is not needed when you give the handleContextMenu function to the onContextMenu handler because (if you write the function above like I have written) the this context is already bound - no additional arrow function needed. You can rewrite that code as follows:

```
    onContextMenu={this.handleContextMenu}
```

You can find a bit more info about this at the bottom of the page at this link https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Without your full code to re-engineer it completely I can't be sure if that's why your code isn't working but that is just one thing that I saw that can help.